# Is there any way to get the AWS QuickSight dataset refresh rate with boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, boto, amazon-quicksight

I have a use case where I need to get the refresh rate of Quicksight datasets programatically with Python for monitoring purposes.

Is there any way to achieve this with boto3?

I have looked up few boto3 functions like `describe_ingestion()`, which has the information on the last refresh time of the dataset, but the result does not have the refresh rate. So, I would like to know is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Is [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/automate-dataset-monitoring-in-amazon-quicksight/) of use? as there is not direct boto3 api to fetch schedule refresh frequency

Comment: Funny you referenced that. I already implemented the use case in the blog post. I am trying to improvise it by adding refresh schedule put for the dataset in another column, so that it will be easy for my support team.